# Which is good approach to write and read output into a file in BASH?

Tags: linux, unix

To write output into a file, I come across with three methods. May I know which One is better to opt and How.

```
1) echo "some outputs" >> file.out
2) exec 3<> file.out
   echo "some Outputs" >&3
   exec 3<-&
3) echo "some outputs" | tee file.out
```

As I know file descriptor are handling by kernal, and It has to communicate to 3 tables, like File Descriptor table, file table, Inode table to access file info. But I see most of the programs uses File descriptors to handle files. I got few below mentioned questions.

```
Q1) How an Command works, Is it an complied code or "C" program or assembly code?
Q2) Is every Command takes different process?
Q3) What is the process behind re directors(<,>, >>,<< )?
```

Comment: _Is every process takes different process?_ - what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, Every command takes separate process ??